# Are there online English proofs of preservation of properties of morphisms by fpqc descent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Accroding to [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faithfully_flat_morphism), the following propositions are proved in EGA.
Are there *online* proofs written in *English*?

Suppose that $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of $S$-schemes. Let $g\colon S' \rightarrow S$ be faithfully flat and quasi-compact, and let $X', Y'$, and $f'$ denote the base changes by $g$.
Then for each of the following properties $P$, $f$ has $P$ if and only if $f'$ has $P$.

```
Open.
Universally open.
Closed.
Universally closed.
A homeomorphism.
A universal homeomorphism.
Quasi-compact.
Quasi-compact and universally bicontinuous.
Quasi-compact and a homeomorphism onto its image.
Quasi-compact and dominant.
Separated.
Quasi-separated.
Locally of finite type.
Locally of finite presentation.
Finite type.
Finite presentation.
Proper.
An isomorphism.
A monomorphism.
An open immersion.
A quasi-compact immersion.
A closed immersion.
Affine.
Quasi-affine.
Finite.
Quasi-finite.
Integral.
```

Comment: Have you looked in the Stacks project?

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Yes, but I could not find them. I haven't checked thoroughly, though. I would like to know the page numbers or proposition numbers in the stacks project if it has the proofs.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal The propositions(or lemmas) in the stacks project regarding the title question are stated differently from EGA.
It is not entirely clear that they are equivalent.
That's why I could not find them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost everything you need is proved in this chapter of the stacks project: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/descent.pdf

You will need to chase things around the stacks project a bit for things used in the proofs but the proofs are all in section 19 pg 42. The main idea of the proofs is the lemma 18.4 on that same page that says if you have a property that is Zariski local, stable under flat base change, and satisfies descent for flat covers of affine schemes by affine schemes, then the property satisfies fpqc descent.

Comment: Could you tell me, for example, the proposition(or lemma) number of the proof for a closed immersion?

Comment: Lemma 19.17 pg 46. Just look at section 19 that starts on pg 42. It  has every property just proved one after another. That whole section is just 30 lemmas one after another each of which is an fpqc local property of morphisms.

Comment: It is not clear to me that Lemma 19.17 solves our problem for a closed immersion.

Comment: Pullbacks of fpqc covers are fpqc covers so you apply all those lemmas directly to the fpqc cover $Y' \to Y$ e.g. $X \to Y$ is a closed immersion iff $X' \to Y'$ is since $Y' \to Y$ is fpqc and closed immersion is fpqc local on $Y$ by the lemma.

Comment: So Lemma 19.17 is stronger than our proposition for a closed immersion.
Is that the reason why its proof uses cohomology?

Comment: No its equivalent. I don't know of a another proof but I'm not surprised it requires cohomology.  I'd consider cohomology a more basic tool than fpqc descent. the standard approach to learning and teaching algebraic geometry covers cohomology before it even does flatness.

Comment: How come it's equivalent? If a family of morphisms $Y_i \rightarrow Y$ has more than two morphisms, each morphism need not be faithfully flat, right?

Comment: You can always replace an fpqc cover $\{Y_i \to Y\}$ with an fpqc cover with only one morphism $Y' \to Y$ where $Y' = \sqcup Y_i$.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks.