# Non-noetherian Chevalley's theorem on locally constructible sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I would like to prove that [closed immersions are preserved by fpqc descent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621573/are-there-online-english-proofs-of-preservation-of-properties-of-morphisms-by-fp)
using the idea of Grothendieck's EGA.

For a starter, I would like to prove the title theorem.
We need some definitions to state it.

**Definition 1**
We say a continuous map $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ of topological spaces is quasi-compact if $f^{-1}(U)$ is quasi-compact for every quasi-comapact open subset $U$ of $Y$.
We say a subset $Z$ of a topological space $X$ is retrocompact if the canonical injection $Z \rightarrow X$ is quasi-compact.

**Definition 2**
Let $X$ be a topological space.
A subset $Z$ of $X$ is called constructible if it is a finite union of subsets of the form $U - V$, where $U, V$ are retrocompact open subsets of $X$.

**Definition 3**
We say a subset $Z$ of a topological space $X$ is locally constructible in $X$ if for every point $x$ of $X$ there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $Z \cap V$ is constructible in $V$.

**Definition 4**
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes.
We say $f$ is quasi-separated if the diagonal morphism $\Delta\colon X \rightarrow X\times_Y X$ is quasi-compact.

**Definition 5**
Let $B$ be an algebra over a ring $A$.
Suppose there exists a surjective $A$-homomorphism $\psi\colon A[X_1, \cdots, X_n] \rightarrow B$,
where $A[X_1, \cdots, X_n]$ is a polynomial ring.
If Ker $\psi$ is a finitely generated ideal, we say $B$ is finitely presented over $A$ or $B$ is a finitetely presented $A$-algebra.

**Definition 6**
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes.
Let $x \in X$.
If there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and an open neighborhood $V$ of $f(y)$ such that 
$f(U) \subset V$ and $\mathcal {O}_X(U)$ is finitely presented over $\mathcal{O}_Y(V)$,
then we say $f$ is locally of finite presentation at $x$.
We say $f$ is locally of finite presentation if it is locally of finite presentation at every point of $X$.

**Definition 7**
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes.
If $f$ is locally of finite presentation, quasi-compact and quasi-separated, we say $f$ is of finite presentation.

**Theorem of Chevalley**
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of finite presentation.
For any locally constructible subset $Z$ of $X$, $f(Z)$ is locally constructible in $Y$.

**My question**
How do you prove it?

**Remark**
Though I plan to post a proof of this theorem, I welcome anyone's proof.
There are usually several different solutions to a mathematical question each of which may have its own merit.

Comment: What does it mean for a continuous map to be quasicompact? The notion is only defined for morphisms of schemes.

Comment: If you already know how to prove it, then what's your question?

Comment: @arsmath How do you prove it? There are usually several different solutions to a mathematical question each of which may have its own merit.